# join tables in a SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I join tables in SQL to modify this query? It is racking my brain

I have three SQL tables that I am trying to run. In my first post the two SQL queries work perfect. But they apply to all products. I need to only have these assigned to two Section ID's.

Script

```
INSERT ProductCustomerLevel (
    ProductID,
    CustomerLevelID
)
SELECT ProductID,
       CustomerLevel
FROM dbo.Product p
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 5 AS CustomerLevel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
) c
```

This maps all ProductID values to Customer Levels 5 & 7. What I want to do here is map all Products only to SectionID's 5345 and 5346. These Section ID's are held within a table Called Sections. There is also another table called ProuductSection. The value of ProductID is in both Product.dbo and ProductSection.dbo.

Within ProductSection the fields are ProdcutID,SectionID so I need to link these sectionid to the query above

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Btw: you don't "*run a table*", you run a *query*.

Comment: MYSQL. I am so tired I could not run a race right now. Ok I need to run/execute this query :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one select all products ID from sections 5345 & 5346

```
SELECT p.ProductID FROM dbo.Product p
INNER JOIN dbo.ProuductSection ps ON (p.ProductID = ps.ProductID)
WHERE ps.SectionID IN (5345, 5346)
```

EDIT: by the way, this is so weird...

```
SELECT ProductID,
       CustomerLevel
FROM dbo.Product p
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 5 AS CustomerLevel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
) c
```

You should not do it this way. Try my way up

Comment: You might find this performs better if you write `WHERE ps.SectionID in (5345, 5346)`

Comment: @DavidWallace: really? Is MySQL's optimizer still that bad?

Comment: Anyway this is cleaner ^^

Comment: No still not getting any results but can see where it's going. Will tweak the code a little as I'm getting Insert errors when trying to use the select statement. But can see how it goes I think.

Will answer the post when I have made some progress. Thanks again all!